# MUI material ui - How to make menu with full width?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to make mobile menu with full width

I tried but it looks like I miss understand something my css rules doesn't applied

this is a live code example :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ucvbgt-sur6ne?file=demo.js

[image]
thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old question but since I was looking for the same thing and found a good solution, I figured I'd post it here.

Your current code is just missing two things: the `marginThreshold` property and a `maxWidth` style. The `marginThreshold` prop specifies how close to the edge of the window the popover can appear. I'm not exactly sure why but I found that the `maxWidth` style also needs to be in there in order for the menu to stretch the full width.

Here's your modified menu component:

```
  <Menu
    position="relative"
    id="basic-menu"
    anchorEl={anchorEl}
    open={open}
    onClose={handleClose}
    marginThreshold={0}
    slotProps={{
      paper: {
        sx: {
          color: 'red',
          width: '100%',
          maxWidth: '100%',
          left: '0px',
          right: '0px',
        },
      }
    }}
    MenuListProps={{
      'aria-labelledby': 'basic-button',
    }}
  >
```

Also, since the `PaperProps` property [has been deprecated](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/popover/#prop-PaperProps), I've swapped that out for [the new `slotProps` pattern](https://mui.com/base-ui/getting-started/usage/#slotprops) as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your Menu to Drawer (with anchor = 'top')

Visit this to learn more : https://mui.com/material-ui/react-drawer/